# SublimeText 3 - можно ли сделать так, чтобы в режиме Plain Text я ставил пробелы не для абзаца, а для строки?

Tags: sublime-text-3

SublimeText 3 - можно ли сделать так, чтобы в режиме Plain Text пробелы ставились не для абзаца, а для строки? Я хочу, чтобы это было, как, например, в WordPad. Прикладываю скриншот.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Судя по циферке слева - это и есть одна строка, просто она отобразилась так из-за размера окна(для удобночитаемости)

Comment: @floydya, ну а можно сделать так, чтобы было, как в WordPad? В WordPad тот же самый текст (та же самая строка), только отступ иначе отображается.